# Implicit view (T) => T guaranteed?

Tags: scala

Imagine a trait like the following (please note that I'm just using this trait for illustrative purposes to pose my question):

```
trait GetString[T, U] {
  def toString(u: U): String = u.toString
  final def getString(t: T)(implicit f: (T) => U) = toString(f(t))
}
```

and some concrete implementations where `T` and `U` are of the same type, like:

```
object LongToString extends GetString[Long, Long]
object DoubleToString extends GetString[Double, Double]

scala> LongToString.getString(100L)
res2: String = 100

scala> DoubleToString.getString(29.3)
res3: String = 29.3
```

Now, here's an implementation where `T` and `U` differ:

```
object BooleanToString extends GetString[Boolean, Int]

scala> BooleanToString.getString(true)
<console>:13: error: No implicit view available from Boolean => Int.
```

Of course, I can fix this by adding an implicit like:

```
implicit val bool2Int = (bool: Boolean) => if (bool) 1 else 0
scala> BooleanToString.getString(true)
res5: String = 1
```

**If `T` and `U` are of the same type, is there always guaranteed to be an implicit view?** In other words, will I only have to provide my own implicit conversion when `T` and `U` differ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. Implicit `T => U` exists for all `T <: U`. This includes the case when `T` and `U` are the same. In other words there is always an implicit cast to the same type or supertype.

This view is defined as `implicit def $conforms[A]: A <:< A` in the `scala.Predef` object.